# Graph Api works but not in Browser

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So, in Facebook Graph Api this link works:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/483520791669390/attending
```

but when i paste it in browser i have this error

```
"message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
"type": "OAuthException",  
 Why?
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a valid access token, it works in Facebook Explorer because a token is supplied there.

> any valid access_token, user_events or friends_events

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need an access token to do such things.

Edit the url to https://graph.facebook.com/483520791669390/attending?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN